# Unable to start Zookeeper with 2 servers in the quorum

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a Zookeeper instance with 2 servers running in the quorum. But when I try to start the first server instance, I get the following exception:

```
2013-11-13 18:26:21,514 [myid:11111111111] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@89] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.lang.RuntimeException: My id 11111111111 not in the peer list
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.startLeaderElection(QuorumPeer.java:479)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:411)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:151)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:111)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: My id 11111111111 not in the peer list

Comment: According to [documentation](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup):

`The id must be unique within the ensemble and should have a value between 1 and 255.`

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper really really does not like have an even number of workers in the cluster.  Having said that, the problem is probably that your myid files do not match your zoo.cfg.  The servers listed in your zoo.cfg have to correspond to the set of values in the myid files.